# Will installing the NVIDIA 375.66 Driver for Ubuntu 14.04 cause a black screen?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, cuda

I have experienced numerous issues installing an NVIDIA driver for my own laptop, which includes a black screen which after purging the NVIDIA driver my screen remains black. In the end, I had to reinstall my entire OS multiple times to get the process right.

However, this time I am trying to install the driver for a computer in my workplace, and the computer consists of a lot of important documents. I can't quite risk removing the entire data from the computer, and so I'd like to ask if the latest proprietary driver will cause any issue installing with Ubuntu 14.04.

Also, there is an option of installing the driver via the CUDA tool. Is it right to say once you install the correct NVIDIA driver, the drivers should not be installed again using the CUDA .run file?

I am installing the driver for the sake of running TensorFlow.

Any help is very much appreciated!